# How to select multiple columns from a table with one specific without duplicate values?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table something like

[image]

and i want

[image]

what query should I write

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using ? `Mysql` is different from `Sql Server`

Answer (score 2):

```
select id,min(name) from mytable group by id
```

EDIT:

```
select min(name) from mytable group by id
```

Comment: and if i want only name displayed now ?

Comment: this is giving me the least alphabet. I want the first row of each id irrespective of the alphabet.

Comment: There is no such concept of "first row" unless you have something to order by.